# Node / Express - Serve-static not working / How to use routes with serve-static files

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having some trouble with routing and serving static files.

My directory structure is like this:

```
app/
--server.js
--controllers/
--directives/
--etc.
assets/
--img/
--css/
--etc.
views/
--partials/
  --view1.jade
  --view2.jade
--index.jade
--layout.jade
--etc.
```

I'd like this to happen:

- **app**/ - Serve **static** files (for example, "GET /app/controllers/controller.js" should send the literal file)
- **assets**/ - Serve **static** files (for example, "GET /assets/css/custom.css" should send the literal file)
- **views**/ - **Dynamic** routing (for example, "GET /partials/view1" uses the routing rules I have set up)

This is how I've set up my server:

```
  ...
//PATHS:
  var viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views');
  var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app');
  var assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets');
  ...
//SERVE-STATIC:
  app.set('views', viewsPath);
  app.use(serveStatic(appPath));
  app.use(serveStatic(assetsPath));
  ...
//ROUTES:
  // serve index and view partials
  app.get('/', routes.index);

  //Partials
  app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
 ...
```

But this is what happens when I visit the index:

```
[.../app]$ node app.server.js 
**Node Version:  v0.12.2
**Express Version:  4.12.3
Path to views:  /myproject/views
Static serving:  /myproject/app
Static serving:  /myproject/assets
Express server listening on port 3000
GET / 304 765.837 ms - -
GET /assets/css/app.css 404 9.851 ms - 31
GET /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 1.837 ms - 41
GET /assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css 404 0.569 ms - 47
GET /assets/css/custom.css 404 0.787 ms - 34
GET /assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js 404 0.458 ms - 47
GET /app/app.modules.js 404 0.639 ms - 31
GET /app/services/services.js 404 0.560 ms - 37
GET /app/controllers/controllers.js 404 1.474 ms - 43
GET /app/filters/filters.js 404 0.662 ms - 35
GET /app/directives/directives.js 404 1.853 ms - 41
GET /assets/js/jquery.min.js 404 3.824 ms - 36
GET /assets/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 0.804 ms - 39
GET /assets/libs/angular/angular-bootstrap.min.js 404 0.624 ms - 57
GET /assets/libs/angular/angular-bootstrap-prettify.min.js 404 0.721 ms - 66
GET /assets/img/logo.png 404 0.465 ms - 39
GET /favicon.ico 404 1.216 ms - 24
```

The "**views**" part ***works***, but the "**assets**" and "**app**" parts ***don't work***.

How do I set up the "serve-static" part to work? Do I still need a route even-though it's listed to serve static files? Would I still need to set up a route and do "sendFile"?

Thanks!

///////////////////////////

#### Update:

///////////////////////////

I tried this:

```
  ...
//PATHS:
  var viewsPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views');
  var appPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app');
  var assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets');
  ...
//SERVE-STATIC:
  app.set('views', viewsPath);
  app.use(serveStatic('app', appPath)); //<--- Changed
  app.use(serveStatic('assets', assetsPath)); //<--- Changed
  ...
//ROUTES:
  // serve index and view partials
  app.get('/', routes.index);

  //Partials
  app.get('/partials/:name', routes.partials);
 ...
```

And also renamed "app.modules.js" to "app-modules.js" but didn't work either :/ Still getting lots of 404's:

```
GET / 200 645.235 ms - 1867
GET /assets/css/app.css 404 9.209 ms - 31
GET /assets/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 2.609 ms - 41
GET /assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css 404 1.297 ms - 47
```

Comment: Try requesting `app.modules.js` without the `app` in the path.  My guess is that it's including all the files in the `app` and `assets` folders, without the folder itself.  You could keep it the way it is, or you could change `app.use(serveStatic(appPath));` to `app.use(serveStatic('app', appPath));`

Comment: @Brennan Thanks! I tried `app.use(serveStatic('app', appPath));` and 
`app.use(serveStatic('assets', assetsPath));` and renamed `app.modules.js` to `app-modules.js` it didn't work :( I think it's on the right track, though!!

Comment: @Brennan using `app.use('/app', serveStatic(appPath));` ended up working, thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the behavior you want, change this:

```
app.use(serveStatic(appPath));
```

...to this:

```
  app.use('/app', serveStatic(appPath));
```

The earlier code specifies serving the contents of your `app` directory statically, but it does not include the `app` part of the path. It basically means "Treat everything in `appPath` as if it was docroot." So, to get (e.g.) `app/server.js` served in your web browser, you would just go to `http://example.com/server.js` and *not* `http://example.com/app/server.js`. By specifying the path in `app.use()`, you get the behavior you want.